# Unable to boot Ubuntu 13.04 (64 Bit)

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 13.04

I Downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 and installed it into a USB drive. Both things were apparently  finished correctly. But after rebooting my PC, I saw the splash screen then came to the desktop but I could see mouse pointer and panel with pink color background. But suddenly that vanished and the screen went to black. After long time mouse pointer appeared with black screen. No any graphical sign. How do I install Ubuntu?

I use Dual core 2.7 GHz prosesor with on board VGA. I had no problem with ubuntu 12.04 and I used 12.04 without any trouble. Please anybody help me. I am not good at English. Thank you.

Comment: I had same problem, when you installed it did you remove USB drive? When I put USB drive in slot from which installation was run, everything worked fine. I've *"solved"* it with fresh install from live CD. When you see GRUB menu, try editing _"Ubuntu"_ line, press <kbd>E</kbd> on your keyboard, find `quiet splash` and replace it with `nomodeset`. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will boot it with changes. See if you can figure it out why it hangs.

Comment: No, I didn't anything. But ubuntu didn't start. But I tried with 13.04 beta 2 iso image. It worked fine but no network connection.

Answer (score 1):

The most stable installation method, would be to download the .ISO file from Ubuntu's homepage, and burning it to a live CD.
[Here's a download link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)